# Dúvida sobre série fibonacci

Tags: java, array, fibonnaci

Por que o meu código não imprimi os 300 primeiros números da série Fibonacci e começa a encontrar números negativos? Qual é o problema desse código? Porque ele vai somente até 92?

```
 final int ARRAY_SIZE = 300; 
    long[] fib = new long[ARRAY_SIZE];


    fib[0] = 0; fib[1] = 1; 
    int n = 2; 
    boolean tooBig = false; 


    while(!tooBig){  
      fib[n] = fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]; //formula!
      if(fib[n]<fib[n-1]) {
    tooBig=true;
  }else
    n++;
}


println("The first "+n+" Fibonacci numbers are:");
//Experiment: Try changing "i<n" to "i<=n".
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
  println("Fib: " + i + " " + fib[i]+ " ");
  }
```

Comment: Ok, mas mas eu encontrar o erro no meu código. Nas perguntas respondidas dadas não está sendo usado arrays.

Comment: Como eu altero o meu código para usar BigInterger? Importei a classe java, mas ainda está dando erro.